# KDB Connection in python 3.9

Tags: python, kdb, python-3.9

In python 3.7.6, I connected to KDB database using QPython module.

After upgrading my Python version to Python 3.9, I can't connect to KDB database.

The reason is QPython is not compatible with Python 3.9.

What are the other alternatives of connecting to KDB database in Python 3.9 ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried the FINOS version? (it was forked from the original a while back) https://pypi.org/project/qPython3/
I haven't had any issues with python 3.8 or 3.11

Comment: @JamesLittle Yes, i've tried qpython3, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [PyKX](https://code.kx.com/pykx/1.6/getting-started/quickstart.html) for interfacing between Python and q, and be sure to also visit the [KX Community discussion board for PyKX](https://community.kx.com/t5/PyKX/bd-p/PyKX) Q&As